# Using jQuery to open page at the bottom.

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, scroll

I am trying to make my page open so that the first thing the viewer sees and continues to see is the footer and bottom of the site. Its a reverse site, so the user scrolls up instead of down, you can check it out (Note it is in very ruff stages right now) Sean-Holt.com (this is my own site and not some trick for free hosting)

I currently have it set up with a Body tag,  which works, but it just looks sloppy and is slow.

I was told jQuery would be the best way of handling this, but i dont know javascript at all and have been watching tutorials all day and searching for a way to implement this and found nothing.

Pleas help, Thank you very very much! 
(note. for clarification, I want the page to open at the picture of the world and scroll up)

Comment: Do you want the page to automaticaly scroll up, or the user keep the control ?

Comment: Note: I would be careful using an image of the Enterprise and that dog on a commercial site. They are owned and copyrighted by other companies. Especially when you are saying "All content and photos are created and are the property of Sean Holt"

Answer (score 2):

You must first include JQuery in your HTML document:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And inside a  tag include the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 300);
});
```

Change "300" to your desired timing in milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript snippet :

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.clientHeight);
```

Will set the scroll bar to the bottom without animations.

Answer (score 0):

for a javascript only solution, try using the `window.scrollTo()` method.

http://login2win.blogspot.com/2010/07/javascript-scroll-to-bottom-of-page.html

Otherwise you can try autoloading a particular url hash (aka anchor) and setting the anchor name tag at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ariel Flesler plugin is simple and easy to use: http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/

Place a unique ID in your img src:

```
<img id="earth2" src="http://sean-holt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Earth2.jpg" />
```

Call the downloaded plugin after jQuery:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://sean-holt.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $.scrollTo('#earth2');   
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You should provide a trusted and reliable CDN.